# Replacing values from a dictionary to a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have first dataframe (df1) as follows:

```
                    Machine Product Value ...
Site TLA    Date            
TH   ABC    08-Oct  A10     RodA    35
            09-Oct  A10     RodA    20
            10-Oct  A11     RodB    22
…                   
ID   ABC    09-Oct  B5      HookY   28
            08-Oct  B8      HookZ   33
…
```

...some of whose columns (Machine and Value) need to be replaced with another dataframe (df2) as follows:

```
                    Machine Value
Site    TLA Date        
TH      ABC 08-Oct  A10     28
            09-Oct  A10     35
            10-Oct  A11     37
…               
ID      ABC 09-Oct  B5      12
            08-Oct  B8      5
…
```

Tried to make a df2.to_dict(orient='index'), but stuck. How to map/replace this dictionary to the Machine, Value in df1?

Answer (score 1):

Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say for certain, but you should be able to do

```
df1.loc[df2.index] = df2
```